# Facebook deep link never return data after app was installed in Android

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I try to use `FB deep link` to get referral info after App installed when I clicked in deep link which was posted at FB. But I received deep link data only if app already installed.

As follow by this doc
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

Application should receive data from deep link, after app has been installed.
But native FB application send to GooglePlay only :

> market://details?id=my.app.package&referrer=utm_source=apps.facebook.com&utm_campaign=fb4a&utm_content=%7B%22app%22%3A0%2C%22t%22%3A1436879844%7D

There is no info from deep link

And one first launch I try use in my launch screen next methods

**AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent**

and **AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData**
but they  get me  null.

**Step by step**

1. I have created hosted api links for android. Where include all possible data for android https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/app_link_hosts
2. Then by FB SDK post this link.
3. Remove my application
4. Click on my post with deep link in native FB application
5. FB ask me to install app. And I have installed app from GooglePLay

**Expected** :
After install receive deep link data on start app.

But if use method described at FB Docs I did not receive any info

Comment: You have to have a broadcast receiver to read the action  com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER

Comment: Hi, I have receiver. But they receiver only data which was at referrer
market://details?id=my.app.package& **referrer=utm_source=apps.facebook.com&utm_campaign=fb4a&utm_content=%7B%22app%22%3A0%2C%22t%22%3A1436879844%7D** 

But this is not info which was at deep link. At deep link I have info like "url":"my.package://init?token=xxx&id=yyy"

Comment: There is a bug open on the Facebook Bug Tool about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/393947180805373. You can follow it for updates.

Answer (score -5):

A heads up that I helped build Branch ([branch.io](https://branch.io)), a linking tool that helps with deep linking through the Play Store. We've had a ton of trouble getting Facebook's methods to work reliably as well. If you use a Branch deep link to host your Facebook App Links, it works 100% of the time through page posts, ads and invites. We have a server to server integration with Facebook, but if that fails, we fall back to our fingerprinting mechanism where we match a browser fingerprint to a device fingerprint. (More on that [here](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/matching_accuracy))

Here's a description of how to get setup so that Branch hosts your Facebook App Links and deep links through install:

1. Head to [start.branch.io](https://start.branch.io) to get your Branch key and configure your link routes
2. Add in the `io.branch.sdk.android` library from Maven Central
3. Setup your manifest for deep linking. You'll start with this:

```xml
<application>
    <!-- Other existing entries -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourapp.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

- Add application subclass so that Branch can monitor for lifecycle changes to detect new deep links.

```xml
<application
    android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp">
```

- Add your intent filters to receive the deep link when the app is already installed

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="yourapp" android:host="open" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

- Add your Branch key

```xml
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="your_key_here" />
```

The final Manifest should look like this:

```xml
<application
    android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp">

    <!-- Other existing entries -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourapp.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="yourapp" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="your_key_here" />

</application>
```

4. Register to receive parameters from Branch deep link click. This is frequently put in onStart of the Activity that you want to use for deep link routing.

```java
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
branch.initSession(new BranchReferralInitListener(){
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
        if (error == null) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found
            // ... insert custom logic here ...
        } else {
            Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```

5. Lastly, to you can create Branch-hosted Facebook App Links in 100 different ways. Here's how to create them dynamically from your app:

```java
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); obj.putString("foo", "bar");
branch.getShortUrl(obj, "sms", "share", new BranchLinkCreateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
        Log.i("MyApp", "Ready to share my link = " + url);
    }
});
```

Happy linking!

Comment: Hi, We had already use branch.io for not facebook app. But branch.io link which was posted in FB and was opened at iOS native FB application not working. (us I know it`s FB bug) So in this case we should use fb deep-link :(

Comment: Serg - Branch links work on Facebook just fine, in all scenarios. You can just paste in the Branch link where you paste in the deep link. Then you can use the deep link router that you use for Branch! Here's some thoughts on debugging the AppLinks stuff https://dev.branch.io/recipes/facebook_appinvites/android/#troubleshooting